# C - Time complexity of nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What should be the Time Complexity of below code?

```
     int j = 0;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         for(i=0;i<n*n ;i++)
         {
             while(j<n)  
             {
                 j++;
             }
         }
     }
```

> My Attempt-

Outer for loop will run just once.
Inner for loop will run n*n times BUT only when i=0, while loop will run for n times. 
Now,

> My point of confusion is -

If I write  n+(n^2−1)∗O(1) as n+O(1)+O(1)+.........+O(1) then I can ignore lower order terms and complexity will be O(n) but then another reasoning  can be a constant amount of work is being done n^2 time so time complexity should be O(n^2)

Similar thing is happening in this question also-
[Time complexity O(N) of nested loops with if-statement: O(N^4)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130145/time-complexity-on-of-nested-loops-with-if-statement-on4)

According to the reasoning given in above link-
I can rewrite the above code simply like-

```
  j=0;
    while(j<n)
    {
        j++;
    }
```

This eliminates those steps in which while loop does not get entered.
So T.C should be O(n).

Both reasoning looks intuitive to me. Please help me.

Comment: I can't tell whether the oddities in your code (like the outer for loop being useless and the while loop only executing the first time) are your mistakes or the author's attempt to make the question trickier.

Comment: "If I write n+(n^2−1)∗O(1) as n+O(1)+O(1)+.........+O(1) then I can ignore lower order terms " Unless the `...` stands for a *constant* number of 1s, you can't remove it. If you could, everything would be `O(1)` (you could just replace any variable with a variable amount of `+1`s and then remove those).

Comment: Author attempted to make it tricker. Thank you so much.
Your this line- 
" Unless the ... stands for a constant number of 1s, you can't remove it. If you could, everything would be O(1)
cleared all my doubts. :)

Comment: You (or the compiler) could rewrite the code that way *if* `i` is never used after the loop (and if it is, you could just add `i=n*n+1` though I'm not sure a compiler would do that automatically), but complexity questions aren't about different code that's semantically equivalent or about compiler optimizations. They're about the code as written, so loops that don't affect the output, still count for the complexity (though of course in the real world you'd never write code like that).

Comment: Ok. thank you. I will take care of it while doing complexity questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time complexity is `O(n^2)`.

The outer loop runs only once, so it can be ignored. The middle loop runs `n*n` times, of which only the first iteration takes `O(n)` steps, the rest is `O(1)`, as `j` will be `n`.

So it's `O(n^2 + n) = O(n^2)`.

Comment: I am sorry, It's exponentiation only. Please edit answer according to it.
 I am editing question.